# Getting latest lines of streaming stdout from a Python subprocess

Tags: python, stream, subprocess

**My goal :** To read the latest "chunk" (N lines) of streaming stdout every M seconds from a subprocess.

**Current code:**

1. start the subprocess
2. reads stdout
3. once I have a chunk of N lines, print it out (or save as current chunk)
4. wait M seconds
5. repeat
6. I have also put code for the moment to terminate the subprocess (which is an endless stream until you hit Ctrl-C)

What I want to achieve is after I wait for M seconds, if for it to always read the ***latest*** N lines and not the subsequent N lines in stdout (they can be discarded as I'm only interested in the latest)

My end goal would be to spawn a thread to run the process and keep saving the latest lines and then call from the main process whenever I need the latest results of the stream.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

sig = signal.SIGTERM

N=9
M=5

countlines=0
p = Popen(["myprogram"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)

chunk=[]

for line in p.stdout:
    countlines+=1
    chunk.append(line)

    if len(chunk)==N:
        print(chunk)
        chunk=[]
        time.sleep(M)

    if countlines>100:
        p.send_signal(sig)
        break

print("done")
```

Comment: I think this would need to create a file-like class which receives the output, throws away older lines and prints the last lines if no new input came for some M seconds (will need a timer object or thread).

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I stumbled upon a solution here:

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/

Eli's "Launch, interact, get output in real time, terminate" code section worked for me.
So far its the most elegant solution I've found.

Adapted to my problem above, and written within a class (not shown here):

```
def output_reader(self,proc):
    chunk=[]
    countlines=0
    for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''):
        countlines+=1
        chunk.append(line.decode("utf-8"))
        if countlines==N:
            self.current_chunk = chunk
            chunk=[]
            countlines=0

def main():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['myprocess'],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    t = threading.Thread(target=output_reader, args=(proc,))
    t.start()

    try:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1) # waits a while before getting latest lines
            print(self.current_chunk)
    finally:
        proc.terminate()
        try:
            proc.wait(timeout=0.2)
            print('== subprocess exited with rc =', proc.returncode)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            print('subprocess did not terminate in time')
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution.  It is a program that you would run as a separate process in the pipeline, which presents a REST API that when queried will return the last N lines that it read on stdin (where N and the port number are supplied on stdin).  It is using `run` in flask so should not be used in situations where the outside world has access to the local server port to make requests, though this could be adapted.

```
import sys
import time
import threading
import argparse
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api


class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'at_eof': False,
                     'lines_read': 0,
                     'latest_lines': []}
        self.thread = None
        self.args = None
        self.stop = False


    def parse_args(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("num_lines", type=int,
                            help="number of lines to cache")
        parser.add_argument("port", type=int,
                            help="port to serve on")
        self.args = parser.parse_args()


    def start_updater(self):
        def updater():
            lines = self.data['latest_lines']
            while True:
                if self.stop:
                    return
                line = sys.stdin.readline()
                if not line:
                    break
                self.data['lines_read'] += 1
                lines.append(line)
                while len(lines) > self.args.num_lines:
                    lines.pop(0)
            self.data['at_eof'] = True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=updater)
        self.thread.start()


    def get_data(self):
        return self.data


    def shutdown(self):
        self.stop = True
        func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
        if func:
            func()
            return 'Shutting down'
        else:
            return 'shutdown failed'


    def add_apis(self, app):

        class GetData(Resource):
            get = self.get_data

        class Shutdown(Resource):
            get = self.shutdown            

        api = Api(app)
        api.add_resource(GetData, "/getdata")
        api.add_resource(Shutdown, "/shutdown")


    def run(self):
        self.parse_args()
        self.start_updater()        
        app = Flask(__name__)
        self.add_apis(app)
        app.run(port=self.args.port)


server = Server()
server.run()
```

Example usage: here is a test program whose output we want to serve:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(100):
    print("this is line {}".format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

And a simple pipeline to launch it (here from the linux shell prompt but could be done via `subprocess.Popen`), serving the last 5 lines, on port 8001:

```
python ./writer.py  | python ./server.py 5 8001
```

An example query, here using curl as the client but it could be done via Python `requests`:

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8001/getdata
{"at_eof": false, "lines_read": 30, "latest_lines": ["this is line 25\n", "this is line 26\n", "this is line 27\n", "this is line 28\n", "this is line 29\n"]}
```

The server also provides an `http://localhost:<port>/shutdown` URL to terminate it, though if you call it before you first see `"at_eof": true`, then expect the writer to die with a broken pipe.